# ColdFusion / IIS 7.5 serves blank pages when URL vars present

Tags: url, coldfusion, iis-7.5

Strangest thing and I cannot find out why this is doing this.

Server details - IIS 7.5 Coldfusion 10 standard

This page: http://www.riverbender.com/sandbox/wtf/ display the following output: Hello World!

Code running:

`<cfset theoutput = 'Hello World!' />
<cfoutput>#theoutput#</cfoutput>`

Now run this page: This page: http://www.riverbender.com/sandbox/wtf/?id=1 <- this will give you a blank page unless you add index.cfm - /sandbox/wtf/index.cfm?id=1

I have cflog running as well. Both /wtf/?id=1 and /wtf/index.cfm?id=1 are being logged, so I'm pretty sure it's not a CF issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the web.config say? It might be a rewrite/rule issue.

Comment: Possible -  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CDz-t-1tsbAGM_SSDw12sffhdrX-qsit4YAmFcpz6Vg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: web.config looks fine to me, but I noticed that the `/?id=1` response returns `Connection: close` (opposite to the .cfm response), hinting that the resource is handled elsewhere.

Comment: Did you modify any ASP related settings for the site? The web.config is for whatever reasons attached to the ASP configuration - even if you don't have a single asp file. If the configuration is broken, the default document might not be respected, what seems to be the case here.

Comment: Nope.  All I did was try to turn on gzip, just trying to get the most speed out of the server.  I followed this tutorial here http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2010/9/24/coldfusion-IIS7-Compression-Issue because simply enabling it in IIS was not getting me gzip in the headers.  I since then reversed the changes shown in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.  FusionReactor had compression support enabled.  Once I disabled the GZIP Requests and GZIP Response the pages where serving again. Thanks to everyone for the help!